# Kafka: What happens to message with null key when log compaction is enabled?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

What happens to message with null key when log compaction is enabled? Are messages with a null key compacted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In current version what happens is this:

> "Currently when a user sends a null key to a log compacted topic, the broker returns CorruptRecordException, which is a retriable exception. As such, the producer keeps retrying until retries are exhausted or request.timeout.ms expires and eventually throws a TimeoutException."

As reported in [Jira KIP-135](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-135+%3A+Send+of+null+key+to+a+compacted+topic+should+throw+non-retriable+error+back+to+user) this is a bit confusing.

In the future if the cleaner solution from KIP-135 (still under discussion as @Ran Lupvoich pointed out) get accepted another behavior should be the following:

> When you try to produce null key to log compacted topic, Kafka should return a new error type INVALID_KEY

Comment: Notice the status, as it seems not yet merged to master. Status
Current state: "Under Discussion"

Discussion thread: here

JIRA:  KAFKA-4808 - send of null key to a compacted topic should throw error back to user PATCH AVAILABLE

Comment: So what happens right now is this: "Currently when a user sends a null key to a log compacted topic, the broker returns CorruptRecordException, which is a retriable exception. As such, the producer keeps retrying until retries are exhausted or request.timeout.ms expires and eventually throws a TimeoutException." 

Correct?

Comment: Yes. And that error should be updated after that fix done I mentioned in the answer