# Kafka: What happens to message with null key when log compaction is turn on?

Tags: apache-kafka

What will happen to messages with null key that are already in the topic if you enable log compaction on the topic ?

Comment: You can find my answer to the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67887343/10866798)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kafka: What happens to message with null key when log compaction is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67885383/kafka-what-happens-to-message-with-null-key-when-log-compaction-is-enabled)

Comment: No, it says what will happen when writing the null key, but I would like to know what will happen to those messages that are already in the topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `Kafka issues` page, after kafka fix version `0.9.0.0`, kafka messages with null keys will be ignored(deleted) when log compaction happens.

You can read more details in here -> [KAFKA-1755](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1755)